# WebView multiple pre-cache with progressBar Android

Tags: android, caching, webview

is it possible to load **multiple** WebPages(including html,images,JS,css ) to WebView cache with real ProgressBar ? I know it is possible to load one page in this way :

```
    String appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
    URL = "https://stackoverflow.com"

    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024 * 1024 * 8);
    webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(appCachePath); 

    if (isNetworkAvailable()) {
        appCachePath = getApplicationContext().getCacheDir().getAbsolutePath();
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG,"Load page from cache");
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_CACHE_ONLY);
    }
```

and it will make possible offline loading of that page, but is it any way to create custom WebView where I will have chance to load multiple URL in array or list, like

```
List<String> urls = new ArrayList<>();
urls.add("https://stackoverflow.com");
urls.add("https://google.com");
urls.add("https://facebook.com");
webView.loadURL(ursl);
```

And also I need a total progressBar for loading of those WebPages. I know I can set WebChromeClient for webView like:

```
 webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
            public void onProgressChanged(WebView view, int progress) {
                Log.d(TAG,"onProgressChanged" + progress);
            } 
        }
```

but it will show progress of loading only one WebPage, when I need total progress of few pages.

I do not want to write my own WebPage grabber, and store it in internal Storage, because it takes a lot of time and probably will cause a lot of different bugs and mistakes.

Please, can you give me some ideas ?

Answer (score 1):

> is it possible to load multiple WebPages(including html,images,JS,css ) to WebView cache with real ProgressBar ?

Not Possible .

Visit Android Doc for [reference](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#loadUrl(java.lang.String)) .